# Creating a jQuery event handler that initiates PHP code

Tags: php, jquery

What I'm trying to do is create some jQuery code that will initiate some PHP code and reload the page when I click on an image. I've created the code below but am confused at what type of event handler in jQuery is necessary to initiate PHP code. I suspect this is borderline AJAX, with the exception being that this is synchronous. Here is the code below.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<style>

img:hover { border:1px solid #021a40; margin: 1px; padding: 1px; color: #000000; 

cursor:pointer;};

</style>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('img').on('click',"img",function(){

$(this).slideUp();

What do I put here?????

});

});

</script> 

<img  src="image.gif" width="50" height="50" />
```

Comment: Why does this have to be jQuery/javascript? Can't you just use a direct link to the PHP-file?

Comment: what is that dear php code you want to run?

Comment: I want the .slideUP() function to work when I click on the image. My fear is the if I create a direct link to the php file then the effects from the jquery will not be seen.

Comment: The php code is an mysql query that updates a field in my database that contains information of the image on the page and a small snippet of code that will send the user to a new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no ajax try:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('img').on('click',"img",function()
   {
       $(this).slideUp('slow',function () 
       {
          window.location = "url/to/phpfile.php?data="+yourdata
       });
   });
});
```

Then in the php file, do your updates and output or redirect to another page.

Regarding your comment above, the second parameter to [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) is a callback function once the animation is complete so you should get the visual feedback before the page transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i think you can do.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img').on('click',"img",function(){
   $(this).slideUp('slow',function () {
      $.ajax({/* your ajax call here will run when the sliding is done */})
   });
  });
});
```

Comment: There is one problem, I can't run AJAX. I'm testing all of this on XAMPP so AJAX is out of the question. I'm ok with redirecting the user to another page. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @jason328 just so you know, XAMPP does not have a problem with ajax. you can run ajax anywhere

Comment: The problem is that you have to put the files that you want to run into another web server when you call them with ajax, correct?

Comment: That is incorrect, XAMPP is a webserver, i understand using a redirect solve your problem, but i think you need to learn more on how ajax work. [AJAX MSD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX)